# Passing data from node to jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, render

The problem is I render a view and send some data

```
console.log(products); // shows an array
res.render('seller/sell',{'shop_id':req.user.shop_id ,'products':products});
```

and I save the data like this in jade

```
input(id='shop_id',type='hidden',name='shop_id',value='#{shop_id}')
input(id='pd',type='hidden',name='pd',value='#{products}')

 if(products !='')
    each val , key in products
        a(href!='home/sell/edit?id=#{val.id} ',class='product')
            img(class='product_thum',src!='#{ val.product_thum}',alt!='#{ val.product_name}',title!='#{ val.product_name}')
            p.product_name #{ val.product_name}
```

and then I try to get the products

```
var d = $('#pd').val();
console.log(typeof d);  //shows string
```

I know that products shuld be a array otherwise

```
    if(products !='')
    each val , key in products
        a(href!='home/sell/edit?id=#{val.id} ',class='product')
            img(class='product_thum',src!='#{ val.product_thum}',alt!='#{ val.product_name}',title!='#{ val.product_name}')
            p.product_name #{ val.product_name}
```

Wont work, but why did I get a string when I need the array?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where are you trying to 'get' the products. Jade is just a templating language that 'compiles' into HTML....

Comment: how does your string look like? you could do something like `var array = string.split(',');`

Comment: what does your array 'products' look like?

Comment: it looks like this {something},{something},{something}

Comment: you can not do var array = string.split(','); because the something in {something},{something},{something} also has ','

Answer (score 5):

You cannot 'store' an array in a hidden input field, but what you could do is store a list of the product id's, something like this:

```
var productIds = products.map(function(product){return product.id}).toString();

res.render('seller/sell',
  {'shop_id':req.user.shop_id ,'products':products, productIds: productIds});
```

Then, in your jade view:

```
input(id='shop_id',type='hidden',name='shop_id',value='#{shop_id}')
input(id='pd',type='hidden',name='pd',value='#{productIds}')

 if(products !='')
    each val , key in products
        a(href!='home/sell/edit?id=#{val.id} ',class='product')
            img(class='product_thum',src!='#{ val.product_thum}',alt!='#{ val.product_name}',title!='#{ val.product_name}')
            p.product_name #{ val.product_name}
```

The value of `pd` will now be a comma separated list of product Ids

Not particularly elegant, but it solves the problem.

Comment: your solution shuld work ， but what if i need all of the data in products

Comment: is there another way pass data from server directly to client side js

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... you can pass your data as a 'model' like you already have - res.render('seller/sell',
  {'shop_id':req.user.shop_id ,'products':products}) - I'm not sure what more you'd need from this??

Comment: well res.render('seller/sell', {'shop_id':req.user.shop_id ,'products':products}) will render the sell view and send the data at same time, what i need is save the data to local storage,so i need a way to get the data in js , I know that I can do another ajax get(),but is it really necessary to query the server twice to get this done? that why i need to get the data in js

Comment: what do you think 'products' is passed to your view as? It's JSON.

Comment: i need json object ,but it passed as string

Comment: is google not working for you?! var myObj = JSON.parse(products);

Comment: You can try to render script tag, with something like "span.hidden <script type="javascript">var products = #{products};</script> or such

Answer (score 0):

Best way to show comma separated string
Example data = abc,pqr,lmn;

```
below code in js file
test = data.toString().split('",");
res.render("show.jade",{list: test});
display the code in jade as
table
 tbody
    each item in list
     tr
      td #{item}
```